# "Я - к окну" (обстоятельство), но "Я - за тобой" (дополнение) - можно ли наоборот?

Tags: члены-предложения, дополнение

С сайта licey.net ([типы односоставных предложений](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_8)):

> Назывные (номинативные) предложения не могут содержать обстоятельств, поскольку этот второстепенный член соотносится обычно со сказуемым (а сказуемого в назывных (номинативных) предложениях нет). Если в предложении содержится подлежащее и обстоятельство (*Аптека – (где?) за углом; Я – (куда?) к окну*), то такие предложения целесообразнее разбирать как двусоставные неполные – с опущенным сказуемым.
>   *Ср.: Аптека находится / расположена за углом; Я бросился / побежал к окну.*
>
> Назывные (номинативные) предложения не могут содержать дополнений, соотносимых со сказуемым. Если такие дополнения в предложении есть (*Я – (за кем?) за тобой*), то эти предложения целесообразнее разбирать как двусоставные неполные – с опущенным сказуемым.
>   *Ср.: Я иду / следую за тобой.*

Можно ли поставить вопросы по другому и соответственно по-иному воспринять роль этих слов в предложении:

- "Я - **к окну**" (к чему? -- дополнение)
- "Я - **за тобой**" (куда? как? -- обстоятельство)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Татьяна в лес; медведь за нею. Это **эллиптическое предложение**.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) ОБ ЭЛЛИПТИЧЕСКИХ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ

Тире может ставиться в эллиптических предложениях особого построения, состоящих из (1) подлежащего и (2) дополнения или обстоятельства (сказуемое в таких предложениях всегда отсутствует). Но разве бывают предложения без сказуемого? А как же предикативность (время, наклонение), они ведь должны быть обязательно выражены?

Но эллиптические предложения – это особый вид предложений. В них **подразумевается действие, но оно может выражаться целой группой глаголов,** например:  Все в подвал (идите, бегите, прячьтесь).

Эти предложения  **не считаются неполными**, так как они **не соотносятся с соответствующими полными предложениями.**
 В эллиптических предложениях возможно наличие или отсутствие тире между двумя частями предложения.

2) ОБ ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВАХ И ДОПОЛНЕНИЯХ

Я провел отпуск (где?) у моих друзей.  Я жил (у кого) у моих друзей. Здесь дополнение имеет **добавочное обстоятельственное значение**.  Мне кажется, мы **напрасно не доверяем падежным вопросам**, которые достаточно ясно говорят о синтаксической роли слова.

Татьяна в лес, медведь за ней. Вопрос очевиден: а медведь куда? Следовательно, это обстоятельство.

Он вперед, я (куда?)за ним. Это обстоятельство, обозначающее направление. Я пришел (за кем?) за ним. Это дополнение со значением объекта.

Comment: Спасибо! Я все равно не понимаю, почему нельзя сказать "Он вперед, я (*за кем?*) за ним" - и счесть *"за ним"* дополнением.. Может, почитаю еще книжек и до меня дойдёт.

Comment: Вы можете считать , что это дополнение с обстоятельственным значением. В этом случае объект, с одной стороны, остается объектом, с другой - используется для обозначения направления.

Answer (score 3):

В предложении "Я - к окну"  второстепенный член "к окну"можно рассматривать и как дополнение, и как обстоятельство. Это т.н. синкретический член, которой отвечает на два вопроса: куда и к чему.

В предложении же  "Я - за тобой" второстепенный член  "за тобой"- дополнение. Здесь не указывается направление, а лишь предмет.

Comment: Но ведь существуют обстоятельства образа действия. "Ты первым пойдешь по мосту? Я - за тобой" (я буду идти как? - за тобой; "я буду держаться за тобой" - держаться *как?* - за тобой)

Comment: На вопрос ''как'' отвечает об-во образа действия. Обстоятельство образа действия обозначает качественную характеристику действия или способ его осуществления («образ действия»).  В предложении ''я пойду по мосту" нет характеристики действия, т.е. здесь не сообщается, каким образом совершается действие, а лишь указывается так сказать предмет, по которому действие совершается действие. значит - дополнение.

Comment: Чтобы понять, какой член предложения представлен на месте пропуска, надо, как верно ответил Александр, заменить тире подходящим к контексту глаголом движения (напр. "направился" куда или к чему) и трактовать член предложения как в обычных случаях. Т.е. все зависит от глагола, который не указан, но подразумевается.

Answer (score 3):

Это вопрос о принятии той или иной терминологии. Мне представляется нелогичным и непродуктивным утверждение, что нельзя называть обстоятельством член неполного предложения с пропущенным сказуемым. Такое предложение имеет смысл только с домысливанием глагола для неназванного движения, с которым и соотносится обстоятельство или дополнение, поясняющее его направление. Наличие или отсутствие глагола, конкретизирующего вид движения, может влиять только на то, соотнесены эти члены предложения со сказуемым, имеющися в явном виде, или с подразумеваемым.

Comment: "Мне представляется нелогичным и непродуктивным утверждение, что нельзя называть обстоятельством член неполного предложения с пропущенным сказуемым." - я не утверждал ничего подобного. (0: Мне просто интересно, как отличить обстоятельство от дополнения в таких случаях.

Comment: Я это говорю о процитированном вами тексте с сайта - там логика такая: нет сказуемого - значит, обстоятельства не существует. Моё предложение: замените тире подходящим к контексту глаголом движения (напр. "направился"  куда или к чему) и трактуйте член предложения как в обычных случаях.